# Why FC going down when primary node shutdown

Tags: sql-server, high-availability, failovercluster, alwayson

I have an alwaysOn AG with 2 node:
Primary node :192.168.66.2
Secondary node :192.168.66.6
Cluster IP:192.168.6.3
Listener IP:192.168.66.10
FileshareWithness
I create cluster with 2nodes in primary server 
Now my problem is if primary sever down,cluster going shutdown!!!!
Tnx

Comment: where is the witness? in the primary node?

Comment: no ,in 192.168.66.4